# CSS - How can I select this <tr>?

Tags: css, forum

[HTML (clicky click)](https://image.prntscr.com/image/jRfn3zceQcaEHi-iun1CKw.png)

I need to select this tr using only CSS, I can't use the ID because i need to select the last tr in this section for every subforum - and all the IDs are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

From what you are saying, it looks like you want to select each item with a `<tr>` tag at the bottom. In the tag add `class="<your custom class here>"`. (Ex: `class="bottomtr"`) In the CSS code, using `.<your custom class here>` style it how you want. It is just like any other selector in CSS and can be formatted the same way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Specifically I want to select every <tr> directly before a .thead class element, and I can't edit the HTML.

Comment: @user7476033 Well, the only way I could think of is finding the ID in CSS code and editing the styles. The question is somewhat vague so I am unable to help you any other way.